# insertar varios registros en una tabla

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

estoy intentando hacer varios registros al mismo tiempo en una tabla pero no lo hace no se que es lo que tengo equivocado este es mi html con mi java script

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
 <head>
    <title></title>
   </head>
   <body style="width: 900px; height: 300px; margin: auto;">


    <div style="background-color: #fafafa; margin: 1rem; padding:  1rem; border: 2px solid #ccc; text-align: center; " class="principal">
<h1>Insertar</h1>
<h2>Productos</h2>
   </div>

   <form style=" text-align: center; margin: 1px solid #ccc; " action="" id="form_insert">

 <?php for ($i=1; $i <=3 ; $i++) { ?>
 <div style="float:left; width:300px; align-content: center; " class="f1-3">
    <label for="">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" required name="nombre[]">
 </div>
 <br>

 <div style="float:left; width:300px; align-content: center;" class="f1-3">
    <label for="">Marca</label>
    <select required name="marca[]">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <br>
   <div style="float:left; width:300px;
    <label for="">Modelo</label>
    <input type="text" required name="modelo[]">
 </div>
   <br>
    <?php  } ?>

     <div style="background-color: #fafafa; margin: 1rem; padding:  1rem; border: 2px solid #ccc; text-align: center; ">
    <input type="submit" value="guardar">
 </div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on( 'submit','#form_insert', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
   url: "App/insertar.php",
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: $(this).serialize(),

  success: function( result ) {
    console.log(result);
   if (!result.error) {
      alert('Los datos se ingresaron con exito');
    }else{
    alert('Los datos no se ingresaron');
   }
 }
  });

});
   </script>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

y este es mi insertar.php

```
   <?php 
    require 'conexion.php';

    $base=$_POST['nombre'];
    $marca=$_POST['marca'];
     $modelo=$_POST['modelo'];

    $cadena="INSERT INTO productos (nombre,marca,modelo) VALUES ";

   for ($i=0; $i <=count($base) ; $i++) { 
   $cadena.="('".$base[$i]."','".$marca[$i]."','".$modelo[$i]."'),";
   }

   $cadena_final = substr($cadena, 0, -1);
   $cadena_final.=";";

   if ($mysqli -> query($cadena_final)); {
   echo json_encode(array("error" =>false));

   }else{
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
   }

   $mysqli->close();

    ?>
```

my problema es que no inserta pero tampoco me manda algún error

Comment: En la línea _<div style="float:left; width:300px;_ te falta un > y para el problema concreto que tienes, puedes volcar $cadena_final y ejecutarla directamente en phpmyadmin para ver qué ocurre exactamente.

Comment: no me muestra nada aun asi no sale ningun error

Comment: Prueba a buscar el error en el fichero error.log, es muy raro que no se muestre ningún error.

Comment: Sigue sin mostrarme algo , creen que sea el jQuery ?

Comment: ¿Has probado a volcar $cadena_final tal como te sugiero en el primer comentario y pegarla directamente en phpmyadmin? ¿La petición AJAX llega a realizarse? prueba a poner un alert antes de esta a ver si llega.

Comment: Has comprobado qeu la conexión a  al Base de datos sea correcta? Prueba de ir  pintando todo los elementos que necesitas, $_POST, La consulta  y como comentan los compañeros pégala directamente en el phpmyadmin, pon algún `console.log('probando paso tal');` por el medio del proceso del ajax, antes de mandar con los parámetros, después y al finalizar.